# How to login saperately from magento frontend using admin credential?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, frontend, login

I have created users with respective their permissions from Magento admin panel. Now I need to login these users from Magento frontend...

**(Kindly note that customer login is different part. I need separate button on Magento frontend for user login)**

Comment: What you have tried ? add Your code.

Comment: i dont have code. i am trying to create user from magento admin panel and login via frontend with separate login. so i dont have any idea. how can i do that.

Comment: Did you get a working functionality/idea?

Answer (score 0):

I get your meaning: You created an admin user for login admin panel, but you want to perform the login action on frontend(i.e. Customer login page), not on admin login page.

Actually Magento 1.9 has a module to perform your task already. You can use [Magento_CrossAreaSessions](https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions) to perform your works. So that you can login as admin on customer page, and vice versa.

Comment: i dont want to login via customer login page. after creating users from admin panel we can login same admin panel . so i need same loin from frontend.

Comment: please specify your complete module i am not getting

Comment: You need a brand new page, right?

Comment: actually i am trying to create user panel on frontend after login it should be redirect to specific page to perform some action

Comment: I'm confused now. Please update the question to specify your needs in details.

Comment: i have tried same extension but it showing username and password invalid.

Comment: That strange, you may submit issue ticket to the author of the module.

Comment: see, i have created users from magento backend. now i want saperate button on frontend. after clicking on this button it redirects to separate login page. after entering username and password new page will be open and showing product filter like backend

Comment: there is no any error in my code. your plugin is not working

Comment: anybody knows answer please help...